# On a simple combination between Thābit ibn Qurra theorem and Wilson-Lagrange

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-sum

I believe that this first claim will be well known in the literature about amicable numbers because it is easy to deduce

**Claim 1.** The primes $p,q$ and $r$ in [Thābit ibn Qurra theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers) satisfy that have the form, respectively, $p$, $2p+1$ and $2p^2+4p+1$.

There are simple consequences of this Claim 1 (for example one can write each of one of the amicable numbers (see the form in previous Wikipedia article, same section) $N:=2^npq$ and $M:=2^n r$ in a amicable pair in terms only of $p$ and $2^n$, or state a closed-form also in terms of $p$ and $n$ for the difference $M-N$) and I tried combine previous claim with Wilson-Lagrange theorem to show the following

**Claim 2.** Let $p$ the prime in Thābit ibn Qurra theorem, then Wilson-Lagrange theorem implies that there exist postive integers $c,c'$ and $c''$ satisfying

$$c'(2p+1)-1=2p(2p-1)(2p-2)\cdots(p+1)p(cp-1)$$
$$\quad\quad\quad c''(2p^2+4p+1)-1=(2p^2+4p)(2p^2+4p-1)\cdots(2p+1)(c'(2p+1)-1)$$

> **Question.** I would like to know if my claims were rights, especially (only is required a proof of) Claim 2. As remark, to deduce Claim 2, I've combined with Claim 1 and three applications of Wilson-Lagrange theorem. Then, can you provide me your calculations to do a comparison with mine? **Many thanks.**

Comment: If in comments you want criticize my approach (the form of the primes in the algorithm+Wilson-Lagrange theorem), improve it or state new claims as a companion of your answer feel free to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claims are right and easy to check ...

**Claim 1**
$$p = 3\cdot2^{n − 1} − 1\\
q = 3\cdot2^n − 1=2\cdot(3\cdot2^{n-1}-1)+1=2\cdot p+1\\
r = 9\cdot2^{2n − 1} − 1=2\cdot9\cdot2^{2n − 2} − 1=2\cdot (3\cdot2^{n-1})^2-1=2\cdot (p+1)^2-1$$

**Claim 2** from [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem)
$$(p-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod{p} \Leftrightarrow \color{#C00}{(p-1)!=c\cdot p-1} \\
(2p)!\equiv -1 \pmod{2p+1}  \Leftrightarrow \color{#C0C}{(2p)!=c'\cdot(2p+1)-1}\\
(2p^2+4p)!\equiv -1 \pmod{2p^2+4p+1}$$
or
$$(2p)(2p-1)...(p+1)p\color{#C00}{(p-1)!}\equiv -1 \pmod{2p+1}\\
(2p^2+4p)(2p^2+4p-1)...(2p+2)(2p+1)\color{#C0C}{(2p)!}\equiv -1 \pmod{2p^2+4p+1}$$
or
$$(2p)...p\color{#C00}{(c\cdot p-1)}\equiv -1 \pmod{2p+1}\\
(2p^2+4p)...(2p+1)\color{#C0C}{(c'\cdot(2p+1)-1)}\equiv -1 \pmod{2p^2+4p+1}
$$

Comment: Many thanks then perfect. Your calculations seems much more clean and understandable than mine. Many thanks also for your effort to do your proof  nice.